# Spreadsheet Service: Reading Data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am following this [tutorial](https://bootstrapping.tools/how-to-autosend-slack-direct-messages-from-google-sheets/#:%7E:text=const%20latest_metrics%20%3D-,sheet.getRange) to read data from a Google Spreadsheet. However, I am trying to find some documentation on that method, but I cannot find it. There's an official [guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#javascript) on how to read from a single range, but it doesn't address the specifics for different sheets. Could someone help me read data or offer skeleton code?

This is what I have so far:

```js
function getLatestRotations() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<SPREADSHEET ID>");
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("<SHEET NAME>")

  const columnFriday = sheet; //method to get column id?
  const columnSunday = sheet;
  
  rotations = {};
  return rotations;
}
```

Comment: The code you've shown above is [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) not [Google Sheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest).  Which of these 2 are you interested in?  From the first you can find ways to getRange(), getValues(), setValues() from different sheets or spreadsheets as well as many other things with simple examples.

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: Hey, I clearly didn't know the difference., Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to get all values in a column

```
function getLatestRotations() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<SPREADSHEET ID>");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("<SHEET NAME>")
  const column = 1;
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,column,sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
}
```